# Rails: times in different time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

A room 'opens' at 9am in San Francisco. I have to record the time correctly in Rails.

```
DateTime.new(2013,11,19,9,0,0) # This produces GMT: Tue, 19 Nov 2013 09:00:00 +0000

DateTime.new(2013,11,19,9,0,0).in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)") # This also records in GMT: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 01:00:00 PST -08:00
```

I would like to get the time as it stands **locally**, i.e.: `Tue, 19 Nov 2013 09:00:00 PST -08:00`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the time zone (a list of options is available at `rake time:zones:all`),

```
time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

You can then do:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone[time_zone].parse("2013-11-19 09:00:00")
```